# how to make sure that cmake codes will run after subdirs

Tags: c++, cmake

Just give a small example to illustrate my problem:

```
project(Test)

set(TestLibName mytest)
subdirs(src) # will generate mytest.dll dynamic library

set_property(TARGET ${TestLibName} PROPERTY FOLDER "test")
```

In this small script, I want to generate the dynamic library with the CMakeLists.txt file in `src` foler, and after that I will set the library's property in the top CMakeLists.txt. However, it seems that it does not work as I have the following error:

```
set_property cannot find Target "mytest". Perhaps it has been created yet.
```

One solution to solve this problem is to put set_property within the CMakeLists.txt that creates the dynamic library (`src/CMakeLists.txt`). If I insistent putting it on top-level CMakeLists.txt file, what can I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use deprecated command [subdirs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:subdirs). Everything works when it is replaced by [add_subdirectory](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:add_subdirectory)